# MongoDB Heroku - not authorized on chatterbot-database to execute command { createIndexes

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I provisioned a MongoDB for my Heroku app and I can connect to the database fine (using a third-party MongoDB UI tool). I created a new user and got the following message back:

```
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "username",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "dbAdmin",
                        "db" : "heroku_340171"
                }
        ]
}
```

However, when running my Django app I get the following error:

```
File "g:\Git\ChatterbotTest\chatterbottest\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from views import FbView
  File "g:\Git\ChatterbotTest\chatterbottest\views.py", line 33, in <module>
    database_uri="mongodb://username:password@ds23123.mlab.com:13938/heroku_340171"
  File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class
    return Class(**kwargs)
  File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\mongodb.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.statements.create_index('text', unique=True)
  File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1529, in create_index
    self.__create_index(keys, kwargs)
  File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1430, in __create_index
    parse_write_concern_error=True)
  File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 232, in _command
    collation=collation)
  File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 419, in command
    collation=collation)
  File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 116, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "g:\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: not authorized on chatterbot-database to execute command { createIndexes: "statements", indexes: [ { unique: true, name: "text_1", key: { text: 1 } } ] }
```

`dbAdmin` should have the permissions to run `createIndexes`. What's going wrong?